# When I store XML data in SQL Server, CDATA is ignored on retrieving the column. How can this be solved?

Tags: sql-server, xml, cdata

```
Select CAST(ValueXML as XML) 
From TableSample
```

returns data without

```
<![CDATA[some Expression]]>
```

Comment: Don't understand. Why would you expect a CDATA?

Comment: I need to store that XML into the database so that I can use it ,as it is, whenever I need. I need CDATA to contain some expressions that can help me decide making decisions on the basis if certain conditions are met.

Comment: What is the data type of your column `ValueXML` ? And please provide a sample of your data you want to cast.

Comment: its like <parameter><![CDATA[empType=='1']]><parameter/>